# Get object from push notification and show in modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app when a task is created it sends a push notification to my device, I need to show the task with all the data in a table view, Im actually sending the data in the notification:

{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "test",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "task": {
        "responsible": "39",
        "userId": "49",
        "taskDescription": "test",
        "topicId": "2",
        "companyId": "1",
        "dueDate": "05/10/2014"
    }
}

but the problem is that I dont know how to take all the task info and get it in an object, can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to register for push notifications

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) 
    {
           // if ios is 8 then this will run
           [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
           [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
          // if ios is 7.x or less this will run
          [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
return YES;
}
```

Worth checking that the application is successfully registered or not using

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

in case of error it will come here, and you can write the reason why it did not registered itself

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Then You can get dictionary from the following delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and from here you can get the keys with the following code

```
NSDictionary *aps_dictionary = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSDictionary *task_dictionary =  [userInfo objectForKey:@"task"];
NSString *responsible = [task_dictionary objectForKey:@"responsible"];
```